# Interface implementation that needs initiliazation

Tags: c#, interface, constructor, initialization

I would like to extract an interface of a class that needs initilization.

```
public class Example<T>
{
    public Example(SomeData data)
    {
        // initialize self with data
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetObjects(SomeData data)
    {
        // extract data
    }
}
```

The problem is that we can't write an interface that would enforce non-default type constructors. I could of course change my class to:

```
public interface IExample<T>
{
    void Initilize(SomeData data);
    IEnumerable<T> GetObjects(SomeData data);
}

public class Example<T> : IExample<T>
{
    public void Initilize(SomeData data)
    {
        // initialize self with data
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetObjects(SomeData data)
    {
        // extract data
    }
}
```

But this is not the same, because when one would instantiate this type could directly call into `GetObjects` which would then result in an exception that instance is not initilized.

### What other options do I have?

Comment: How about an abstract class to inherit from instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is just an interface, you shouldn't care about the constructor.  The interface defines what the implementations can do but not specifically how they do it or what order methods are called in.

How can you realistically say that in the future there won't be some implementation of the interface that works differently and doesn't require the constructor?

Comment: So are you saying that I should be throwing uninitialized exception in my particular class that **does need initialization**?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik No, he's saying that the interface shouldn't enforce that the class be initialized.  It is up to the class implementing the interface to ensure that it is initialized if (and only if) it needs to be.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik, the classes can still have a constructor, it's not enforced by the interface 'cause it's not relevant to the interface.  This leaves you the flexibility to have some classes later that use a different interface.

Comment: I know all that. The particularity of my class is such that initialization will **always be** needed whatever the implementation. All of my interface implemented classes will need initialization upon data retrieval. And it's only after initialization that they become useful.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  The constructor arguments are an implementation detail of the class- they are irrelevant to the interface unless you decide to make `GetObjects` a read/write property.

Somewhere you are constructing a concrete instance, and you already know about the class itself there, so you know that you need to pass certain constructor arguments.

If you really want to enforce this idea that "All IExamples must be constructed with some arguments" externally, use a Factory pattern:

```
public static class ExampleFactory {
    public static IExample<T> MakeAnExample(SomeData data) {
        // return some concrete implementation... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if I do create a Factory/Builder that doesn't prevent developers to manually instantiate implementations of `IExample<T>`... Factory in this case would just be a wrapper of some sort...

Comment: @RobertKoritnik One standard practice would be that the factory, interface, and implementation are all in a class library.  The actual implementations are `internal` while the factory and interface are `public`.  Because of this (barring reflection) the concrete classes can only be created by going through the constructor.

Comment: If you don't want anyone external to your project to create an instance of this interface just make the constructors of the implementations `internal`.  You can't stop an external party from implementing the interface themselves of course.